# WSimport tools generates a client stub with missing members

Tags: java, web-services, wsimport

I have designed a simple web services interface using Metro 2.2.1. When I run the wsimport utility that comes with Java SE (build 1.6.0_24-b07-334) and point it to the WSDL URL location, it generates the client stub code, but the code has missing methods. I am stumped as to why this is the case and would appreciate any pointers.

The main web service class AutoUpdateAPI has the method:

```
public UpdateActionWS getLatestUpdate(@WebParam(name = "application") String application,     @WebParam(name = "version")  String version,@WebParam(name = "entries") UpdateItemWS[] entries, @WebParam(name = "license") String license);
```

It returns an UpdateActionWS class that has the following definition:

```
public class UpdateActionWS {

protected String url;
protected String version;
protected boolean forcedInstall = false;

protected UpdateItemWS[] additions;
protected UpdateItemWS[] subtractions;
protected UpdateItemWS[] changes;

public UpdateActionWS() {

}

protected UpdateActionWS(String url, String version, boolean forcedInstall, UpdateItemWS[] additions, UpdateItemWS[] subtractions, UpdateItemWS[] changes) {
    this.additions = additions;
    this.subtractions = subtractions;
    this.changes = changes;
    this.url = url;
    this.version = version;
    this.forcedInstall = forcedInstall;
}

@WebMethod
public UpdateItemWS[] getAdditions() { return additions; }
@WebMethod
public UpdateItemWS[] getSubtractions() { return subtractions; }
@WebMethod
public UpdateItemWS[] getChanges() { return changes; }


@WebMethod
public String getUpdateURL() { return url; }

@WebMethod
public String getVersion() {
    return version;
}

@WebMethod
public boolean getForcedInstall() {
    return forcedInstall;
}
@WebMethod
public void setForcedInstall(boolean forcedInstall) {
    this.forcedInstall = forcedInstall;
}
}
```

Now, when the client stub is generated, the output for this class is as follows:

```
/**
* <p>Java class for updateActionWS complex type.
* 
* <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
* 
* <pre>
* &lt;complexType name="updateActionWS">
*   &lt;complexContent>
*     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
*       &lt;sequence>
*         &lt;element name="forcedInstall" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}boolean"/>
*       &lt;/sequence>
*     &lt;/restriction>
*   &lt;/complexContent>
* &lt;/complexType>
* </pre>
* 
* 
*/
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "updateActionWS", propOrder = {
"forcedInstall" 
})
public class UpdateActionWS {

protected boolean forcedInstall;

/**
 * Gets the value of the forcedInstall property.
 * 
 */
public boolean isForcedInstall() {
    return forcedInstall;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the forcedInstall property.
 * 
 */
public void setForcedInstall(boolean value) {
    this.forcedInstall = value;
}

}
```

My question is: why does it disregard the other methods? I have tried using wsimport utility that comes with Apache-CXF-2.3.3. I've tried adding latest JAX-WS libs to Java's endorsed lib, but no luck. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Your class, `UpdateActionWS` must be annotated with `@WebService` perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the issue. It is actually annotated. I just omitted it from above:


import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService()
public class UpdateActionWS {
 ..

Comment: I figured it out. 

You can't only have getters. You must also have setters! Argh!

Comment: @user1387012. Your last comment helped. Thanks.